# Undefined variable GET issue

Tags: php, encryption

I'm still relatively new to PHP, I'm trying to assist someone with a PHP issue they're having. However for some reason I just cannot see what it is that I'm doing wrong.

I attempted to echo the "$params" and got this string:

```
clientid=30608&password=passphrase&oid=&chargetype=Auth¤cycode=826&total=
```

which clearly shows that the "oid=" and the "total=" records are missing, which was because in the **old** code, the oid and total section displayed in the code below, were commented out, which meant they weren't being encrypted along with the rest of the params.

After removing the #, I attempted again, however I received this notice:

Notice: Undefined variable: GET_ in /home/public_html/payments.php on line 232

Notice: Undefined variable: GET_ in /home/public_html/payments.php on line 234

I understand it's `$_GET` (also in the code) and not `$GET_` however the error still shows it like that.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
<?php require_once('mulgas1.php'); ?>
<?php session_start(); ?>
<?php
if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
{
  $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;

  $theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

  switch ($theType) {
    case "text":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;    
    case "long":
    case "int":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "double":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . doubleval($theValue) . "'" : "NULL";
      break;
    case "date":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;
    case "defined":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
      break;
  }
  return $theValue;
}
}

$colname_InvoicePayments = "-1";
if (isset($_SESSION['recordadded'])) {
  $colname_InvoicePayments = (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) ? $_SESSION['recordadded'] : addslashes($_SESSION['recordadded']);
}
mysql_select_db($database_mulgas1, $mulgas1);
$query_InvoicePayments = sprintf("SELECT * FROM InvoicePayments WHERE IP_ID = %s", GetSQLValueString($colname_InvoicePayments, "int"));
$InvoicePayments = mysql_query($query_InvoicePayments, $mulgas1) or die(mysql_error());
$row_InvoicePayments = mysql_fetch_assoc($InvoicePayments);
$totalRows_InvoicePayments = mysql_num_rows($InvoicePayments);
?><!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>MULGAS LIMITED - Competitive Prices on Boiler Service, Installation, Gas Safety Checks, PAT Testing - Contact Us For Details</title>
<meta name="description" content="MULGAS SERVICES - Established Corgi Registered Gas Engineers. Services include gas installation, service, repair, upgrades, boiler service and replacement. Gas oven and fire installation is another MULGAS service. MULGAS are approved to carry out gas and electrical landlord safety checks. Based in Woking and operating in Surrey and South West London." />
<meta name="keywords" content="mulgas, gas, service, installation, install, repair, upgrade, boiler, replacement, oven, cooker, fire, hot water, central heating, heating, safety, check, landlord, electrical, tenant, UK gas safety, gas safety and electrical checks, inspections, gaselec, gas-elec, british, UK, surrey, london, woking, guildford, engineer, engineers, carbon monoxide, CO, landlords, estate agents, letting agents, property management,solar heating, air source heat pumps, mulgas ltd, mulgas limited, gas boiler engineers, weybridge, west byfleet, camberley, farnham, farnborough, chertsey, addlestone, ashford, staines, bagshot, kingston, surbiton, epsom, esher, leatherhead, cobham, oxshott, chobham, virginia water, sunningdale, ascot, bracknell, gas safety checks, lgsc, cp12, pat, central heating repairs, systems, radiators, solar, renewable, underfloor heating, carbon monoxide, plumbing" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://mulgas.co.uk/wp-content/themes/Mulgas/style.css" media="screen" />
<meta name="author" content="Graham Heels - www.morgan-gould.com" />
<meta name="revisit-after" content="1 week" />
<meta name="robots" content="all" />
<style type="text/css">









body,td,th {
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #28335F;
}



.style2 {
    font-size:25px;
}















-->
</style>
<script src="Scripts/AC_RunActiveContent.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script language="JavaScript1.2" type="text/javascript" src="Nav2/mm_css_menu.js"></script>
<script type="text/JavaScript">
<!--
function MM_preloadImages() { //v3.0
  var d=document; if(d.images){ if(!d.MM_p) d.MM_p=new Array();
    var i,j=d.MM_p.length,a=MM_preloadImages.arguments; for(i=0; i<a.length; i++)
    if (a[i].indexOf("#")!=0){ d.MM_p[j]=new Image; d.MM_p[j++].src=a[i];}}
}

function MM_findObj(n, d) { //v4.01
  var p,i,x;  if(!d) d=document; if((p=n.indexOf("?"))>0&&parent.frames.length) {
    d=parent.frames[n.substring(p+1)].document; n=n.substring(0,p);}
  if(!(x=d[n])&&d.all) x=d.all[n]; for (i=0;!x&&i<d.forms.length;i++) x=d.forms[i][n];
  for(i=0;!x&&d.layers&&i<d.layers.length;i++) x=MM_findObj(n,d.layers[i].document);
  if(!x && d.getElementById) x=d.getElementById(n); return x;
}

function MM_nbGroup(event, grpName) { //v6.0
  var i,img,nbArr,args=MM_nbGroup.arguments;
  if (event == "init" && args.length > 2) {
    if ((img = MM_findObj(args[2])) != null && !img.MM_init) {
      img.MM_init = true; img.MM_up = args[3]; img.MM_dn = img.src;
      if ((nbArr = document[grpName]) == null) nbArr = document[grpName] = new Array();
      nbArr[nbArr.length] = img;
      for (i=4; i < args.length-1; i+=2) if ((img = MM_findObj(args[i])) != null) {
        if (!img.MM_up) img.MM_up = img.src;
        img.src = img.MM_dn = args[i+1];
        nbArr[nbArr.length] = img;
    } }
  } else if (event == "over") {
    document.MM_nbOver = nbArr = new Array();
    for (i=1; i < args.length-1; i+=3) if ((img = MM_findObj(args[i])) != null) {
      if (!img.MM_up) img.MM_up = img.src;
      img.src = (img.MM_dn && args[i+2]) ? args[i+2] : ((args[i+1])? args[i+1] : img.MM_up);
      nbArr[nbArr.length] = img;
    }
  } else if (event == "out" ) {
    for (i=0; i < document.MM_nbOver.length; i++) {
      img = document.MM_nbOver[i]; img.src = (img.MM_dn) ? img.MM_dn : img.MM_up; }
  } else if (event == "down") {
    nbArr = document[grpName];
    if (nbArr)
      for (i=0; i < nbArr.length; i++) { img=nbArr[i]; img.src = img.MM_up; img.MM_dn = 0; }
    document[grpName] = nbArr = new Array();
    for (i=2; i < args.length-1; i+=2) if ((img = MM_findObj(args[i])) != null) {
      if (!img.MM_up) img.MM_up = img.src;
      img.src = img.MM_dn = (args[i+1])? args[i+1] : img.MM_up;
      nbArr[nbArr.length] = img;
  } }
}
//-->
</script>
</head>

<body onload="MM_preloadImages('Nav2/Mulgas_Nav2_r1_c1_f2.png','Nav2/Mulgas_Nav2_r1_c1_f4.png','Nav2/Mulgas_Nav2_r1_c3_f3.png','Nav2/Mulgas_Nav2_r1_c3_f2.png','Nav2/Mulgas_Nav2_r1_c3_f4.png','Nav2/Mulgas_Nav2_r1_c4_f3.png','Nav2/Mulgas_Nav2_r1_c4_f2.png','Nav2/Mulgas_Nav2_r1_c4_f4.png','Nav2/Mulgas_Nav2_r1_c6_f3.png','Nav2/Mulgas_Nav2_r1_c6_f2.png','Nav2/Mulgas_Nav2_r1_c6_f4.png','Nav2/Mulgas_Nav2_r1_c8_f3.png','Nav2/Mulgas_Nav2_r1_c8_f2.png','Nav2/Mulgas_Nav2_r1_c8_f4.png','Nav2/Mulgas_Nav2_r1_c1.png','Nav2/Mulgas_Nav2_r1_c1_f3.png','Nav3/Mulgas_Nav2_r1_c1_f3.png','Nav3/Mulgas_Nav2_r1_c1_f2.png','Nav3/Mulgas_Nav2_r1_c1_f4.png','Nav3/Mulgas_Nav2_r1_c3_f3.png','Nav3/Mulgas_Nav2_r1_c3_f2.png','Nav3/Mulgas_Nav2_r1_c3_f4.png','Nav3/Mulgas_Nav2_r1_c4_f3.png','Nav3/Mulgas_Nav2_r1_c4_f2.png','Nav3/Mulgas_Nav2_r1_c4_f4.png','Nav3/Mulgas_Nav2_r1_c6_f3.png','Nav3/Mulgas_Nav2_r1_c6_f2.png','Nav3/Mulgas_Nav2_r1_c6_f4.png','Nav3/Mulgas_Nav2_r1_c8_f3.png','Nav3/Mulgas_Nav2_r1_c8_f2.png','Nav3/Mulgas_Nav2_r1_c8_f4.png','Nav3/Mulgas_Nav2_r1_c10_f3.png','Nav3/Mulgas_Nav2_r1_c10_f2.png','Nav3/Mulgas_Nav2_r1_c10_f4.png','Nav3/Mulgas_Nav2_r1_c12_f3.png','Nav3/Mulgas_Nav2_r1_c12_f2.png','Nav3/Mulgas_Nav2_r1_c12_f4.png','Nav3/Mulgas_Nav2_r1_c14_f3.png','Nav3/Mulgas_Nav2_r1_c14_f2.png','Nav3/Mulgas_Nav2_r1_c14_f4.png','Nav3/Mulgas_Nav2_r1_c16_f3.png','Nav3/Mulgas_Nav2_r1_c16_f2.png','Nav3/Mulgas_Nav2_r1_c16_f4.png')"><div id="main-content">

    <div id="main-content-page">

        <div id="main-content-inside-page">
        <a href="http://www.mulgas.co.uk"><img src="http://mulgas.co.uk/wp-content/themes/Mulgas/images/logo-pay.png" /></a>
<div id="design">








  <div id="MainText1">
    <table width="100%" bgcolor="#fff">
      <tr>
        <td width="5%">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="73%">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="22%">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><span class="style2">Paying Your Invoice With A Debit Or Credit Card</span></td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><?php # echo "record added =>" . $_SESSION['recordadded'] . "<=   " ;?></td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td height="502">&nbsp;</td>
        <td>     
        <?php

#the following function performs a HTTP Post and returns the whole response
function pullpage( $host, $usepath, $postdata = "" ) {

# open socket to filehandle(epdq encryption cgi)
$fp = fsockopen('ssl://'. $host, 443, &$errno, &$errstr, 60);

#check that the socket has been opened successfully
 if( !$fp ) {
    print "$errstr ($errno)<br>\n";
 }
 else {

    #write the data to the encryption cgi
    fputs( $fp, "POST $usepath HTTP/1.0\n");
    $strlength = strlen( $postdata );
    fputs( $fp, "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\n" );
    fputs( $fp, "Content-length: ".$strlength."\n\n" );
    fputs( $fp, $postdata."\n\n" );

    #clear the response data
   $output = "";


    #read the response from the remote cgi 
    #while content exists, keep retrieving document in 1K chunks
    while( !feof( $fp ) ) {
        $output .= fgets( $fp, 1024);
    }

    #close the socket connection
    fclose( $fp);
 }

#return the response
 return $output;
}

#define the remote cgi in readiness to call pullpage function 
$server="secure2.epdq.co.uk";
$url="/cgi-bin/CcxBarclaysEpdqEncTool.e";

#the following parameters have been obtained earlier in the merchant's webstore
#clientid, passphrase, oid, currencycode, total
$clientid = "30608";
$passphrase = "passphrase";
$oid = $_GET['InvoiceNo'];
$currencycode = "826";
$total = $_GET['AmountDue'];

$params="clientid=30608";
$params.="&password=passphrase";
$params.="&oid=" . $row_InvoicePayments['IP_Invoice_Number']; 
$params.="&chargetype=Auth";
$params.="&currencycode=826";
$params.="&total=" . $row_InvoicePayments['IP_Amount_Due'];

#$params="clientid=$clientid";
#$params.="&password=$passphrase";
#$params.="&oid=$oid";
#$params.="&chargetype=Auth";
#$params.="&currencycode=$currencycode";
#$params.="&total=$total";

#perform the HTTP Post
$response = pullpage( $server,$url,$params );

#split the response into separate lines
$response_lines=explode("\n",$response);

#for each line in the response check for the presence of the string 'epdqdata'
#this line contains the encrypted string
$strEPDQ = '';
$response_line_count=count($response_lines);
for ($i=0;$i<$response_line_count;$i++){
    if (preg_match('/epdqdata/',$response_lines[$i])){
        $strEPDQ=$response_lines[$i];
    }
}
?>
          <p align="left">Thank you for entering your invoice details and agreeing to the Terms and Conditions. 
          <p align="left">By pressing the Complete Payment button below you will be taken to the ePDQ payment page.          
          <p align="left">Once you have succesfully processed a payment through Barclaycard's ePDQ system you will return to <br />
            the Mulgas web site. 
          <p align="left">Mulgas Limited are a limited company based in the UK.           
          <blockquote>
            <p align="left">Company Registration Number : <strong>6240616 </strong></p>
            <p align="left">VAT Number : 
              <strong>GB 733 7166 30            </strong>
            </p>
          </blockquote>
          <FORM action="https://secure2.epdq.co.uk/cgi-bin/CcxBarclaysEpdq.e" method="POST">
            <div align="left"><?php print $strEPDQ; ?>
              <INPUT type="hidden" name="returnurl" value="http://www.mulgas.co.uk/completed_payment.php">
              <INPUT type="hidden" name="merchantdisplayname" value="Mulgas Services">
              <INPUT TYPE="submit" VALUE="Complete Payment">
            </div>
          </FORM>
        </p>
        <div align="center"><img src="images/CC_Warning_1.gif" width="400" height="230" /></div>
        <p>&nbsp;</p></td>
        <td align="right"><img src="images/Prices_Panel_right_200w_500h_1.gif" width="200" height="500" hspace="10" border="0" usemap="#Map3" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
    <div id="bottomSectionNotIndex"><img src="images/Bottom_Narrow_Footer_970w_20h_1.gif" border="0" usemap="#Map2" />
<map name="Map2" id="Map2">
  <area shape="rect" coords="7,1,271,17" href="mailto:service@mulgas.co.uk" />
</map></div>
</div>


<map name="Map3" id="Map3"><area shape="rect" coords="3,6,195,492" href="second opinion.html" />
</map></div>
        <!-- #main-content-inside-page -->

    </div>
    <!-- #main-content-page -->

</div>
<!-- #main-content --></body>
</html>
<?php
mysql_free_result($InvoicePayments);
?>
```

Comment: Did you upload the edited file(where you have changed `$GET_` into `$_GET`?

Comment: $oid = $_GET['InvoiceNo'];
$currencycode = "826";
$total = $_GET['AmountDue'];

Comment: I've been editing it while live, so I've tested the change, still comes up with that notice

Answer (score 1):

change

```
$oid = $_GET['InvoiceNo'];
$currencycode = "826";
$total = $_GET['AmountDue'];
```

to

```
$oid = (isset($_GET['InvoiceNo']) ? $_GET['InvoiceNo'] : null );
$currencycode = "826";
$total = (isset($_GET['AmountDue']) ? $_GET['AmountDue'] : null );
```

basic idea is those parameters you are searching on, are not declared.
You should ALWAYS check if the viriable exist before u are using it

Comment: After changing the code to what you stated, the notice has gone from the payments page, so I thank you for that. I still have an issue with the records not showing in the string, however that's another issue not related to the initial question.

Comment: i see that you set your params like this:  
`$params="clientid=30608";  
$params.="&password=passphrase";
$params.="&oid=" . $row_InvoicePayments['IP_Invoice_Number']; `
$params.="&chargetype=Auth";
$params.="&currencycode=826";
$params.="&total=" . $row_InvoicePayments['IP_Amount_Due'];`
<br/>
but i dont see anywhere the AmountDue and InvoiceNo <br/>

and also what i wrote on top is :  

`if (isset($_GET['AmountDue'])){  
$_GET['AmountDue'] = $_GET['AmountDue'];  
} else {  
$_GET['AmountDue'] = null;  
}

Comment: At the top of the code, it calls it in via SQL, as I have them all saved in the database. It should call up IP_Amount_Due from the database into "total" and then call up IP_Invoice_Number from the database into "oid"

Comment: aham, ok it is a different problem then. Probably some wrong where condition in your query :-)
feel free to give more details if you cant figure it out
Have a nice day.

Comment: I'm already struggling as it is, I just can't determine what's wrong in the code as my knowledge isn't that extensive. However, thank you for your help :)